# Report does not execute on computers other than my own

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

My application does not work on any computer but my own. When I open the exe from the bin folder on my computer it brings up the report and I can run it no problem. However when I go to another computer it crashes and displays this error:

```
Problem Event Name:        CLR20r3
Problem Signature 01:      CrystalTest.exe    
Problem Signature 02:      1.0.0.0    
Problem Signature 03:      57d0272d    
Problem Signature 04:      CrystalDecisions.Shared    
Problem Signature 05:      13.0.17.2096
Problem Signature 06:      576134be
Problem Signature 07:      69d
Problem Signature 08:      1
Problem Signature 09:      System.TypeInitialization
OS Version:                6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
Locale ID:                 1033
Additional Information 1:  0a9e
Additional Information 2:  0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
Additional Information 3:  0a9e
Additional Information 4:  0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

I created a new C# windows form application project, added the existing Crystal Report as a New Item, added a CrystalReportViewer to the form, and added this code:

```
private void crystalReportViewer1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ClinicLetter rpt = new ClinicLetter();
    crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
}
```

The project properties target framework is 4.5. My computer uses:

- Windows 7
- Visual Studio 2015
- Crystal Reports XI Release 2 .NET 2005 Server
- SAP Crystal Reports Runtime engine for .NET Framwork (64-bit)
- SAP Crysalt Reports, version for Microsoft Visual Studio
- Crystal reports viewer 2011 sp4

The computer that doesn’t work uses:

- Windows 7
- SAP Crystal Reports Runtime engine for .NET Framwork (64-bit)
- Crystal reports viewer 2011 sp4
- Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. I looked at the reference paths for the Crystal Reports .NET framework, and the application was using the 32-bit folder directory. But the computer had 64 bit installed.